# Getting log4j error when setting up kafka docker compose

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose, log4j, apache-kafka-connect

I had a docker compose file that allowed me to set up kafka running on docker. Now I'm trying to add kafka-connect to it but I'm getting this error:
[image]

My docker compose up file is the following, which I adapted from examples I found online:

```
version: '2.1'
services:
  kafka:
    image: wurstmeister/kafka
    container_name: kafka
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_DELETE_TOPIC_ENABLE: 'true'
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "TOPIC:3:1"
  zookeeper:
    image: wurstmeister/zookeeper
    ports:
      - 2181:2181
  connect:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka-connect
    hostname: localhost
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
      - kafka
    ports:
      - 8083:8083
    environment:
      CONNECT_BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS: kafka:9092
      CONNECT_REST_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: localhost
      CONNECT_REST_PORT: 8083
      CONNECT_GROUP_ID: compose-connect-group
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-configs
      CONNECT_CONFIG_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_OFFSET_FLUSH_INTERVAL_MS: 10000
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-offsets
      CONNECT_OFFSET_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC: docker-connect-status
      CONNECT_STATUS_STORAGE_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
      CONNECT_KEY_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.storage.StringConverter
      CONNECT_VALUE_CONVERTER: org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
      CONNECT_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
```

I have no idea how to set up the log4j configuration. I have added an example config file in the directory of the docker compose, but no luck.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> how to set up the log4j configuration

Add another variable. ([Copied from existing Confluent Docker-Compose stack](https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.0.1-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml))

```
CONNECT_LOG4J_LOGGERS: org.apache.zookeeper=ERROR,org.I0Itec.zkclient=ERROR,org.reflections=ERROR
```

---

Also, you have an error in your Kafka image. You should be using `KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: kafka`. Otherwise, Connect will not work.

Comment: Thanks!! The warning didnt disappear, but it clearly was not my problem, because as soon as I changed the host name as you suggested, it almost worked. Now it's complaining about the plugin paht (i think). I get a (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed) java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError but have no idea how to fix it... Any ideas?

Comment: Well, you're getting actual error logs now, so it's only part of the solution. I suggest you just copy the connect service completely from the linked file... This plugin path? https://github.com/confluentinc/cp-all-in-one/blob/7.0.1-post/cp-all-in-one-community/docker-compose.yml#L73

Comment: Hey again! I managed a workaround regarding the logs but I'm still running into org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed:86)
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError. I have read online that this is due to lack of support to ARM. Do you know of any solution/workaround? Thank you!!